# how to create a calculator like interface with xaml?

Tags: xaml, virtualizingstackpanel

I wish to use XAML to create a calculator like interface.It should contain buttons upto 1000.
I've read about virtualizing stack panel but i'm not sure how to use it with a listbox and do data binding with that list for the content. Can you please help me with virtualizing stack panel concept

Answer (score 0):

`ListBox` includes a Virtualizing `StackPanel` by default, so you dont need to worry about it, or how to implement it. FYI, the Virtualizing `StackPanel` only creates UI elements (in your case the Buttons), when they come into View. An aditional improvment is to switch on container Recycling:

```
<ListBox VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="true" VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling" />
```